# Deny IP using wildcard * in CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare

How do I deny a list of IP addresses using wildcard * character? I tried wildcard * but the input field is not accepting * character.

[image]

Is it possible to deny IP using wildcard * in CloudFlare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to block something like `123.123.123.*` if so you probably have to use [CIDR notation](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsp/article.php/3566521/Networking-101-Understanding-Subnets-and-CIDR.htm)

In your case it would be `123.123.123.0/24`

However I note it also says *IP range* so it is likely `123.123.123.0-123.123.123.255` would work as well

Comment: Many thanks, Steve. `123.123.123.0/24` is working like a charm. However `123.123.123.0-123.123.123.254` seems not working. See the screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju0nm3k78n61y03/ip_range_notation.png?dl=0)

Comment: @RaviJoshi perhaps they have an odd way of entering it.  As long as CIDR works, you have something to learn that still messes with my head